# Can't do and set row operation on a Pandas dataframe while I iterate over it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I  want to do a weekbyweek change/comparison (which I can do using shift), the catch is that I only want to compare weeks for each category (so when the next category starts at week 1, I don't want to compare that to the last category week 51).

```
|  Category  |   Weeknumber   |  BruttoTonnes  |
     Apple           1                15        
     ...            ...              ...
     Apple           51                8
     Pear            1                 5
     ...            ...              ...
     Pear            51               12
```

Here is my solution, that sadly doesn't do anything with my dataframe for unknown reasons:

```
for element in df.Category.unique():
    print(df[df.Category == str(element)]['Category']) # This one works, so that is all good  
    df[df.Category == str(element)]['WeekOverWeek%'] = ((df[df.Category == str(element)]['BruttoTonnes'].shift(1)/df[df.Category == str(element)]['BruttoTonnes'])-1)*100
```

The result of this is nothing. No error, but no result as well.

Comment: [**Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)

Comment: Solution: `df.groupby('Category')['BurttoTonnes'].pct_change()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing a merge to itself, I avoid doing any loops, so the whole thing is vectorised, so should be fast

```
import pandas as pd

# set some sample dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame([['Apple',51,20],['Apple',52,19],['Apple',1,14],['Apple',2,15.2],
    ['Apple',3,17],['Apple',4,17],['Apple',5,18],
    ['Orange',51,10.5],['Orange',52,9],['Orange',1,4],['Orange',2,7],
    ['Orange',3,8]],
    columns=['Category','WeekNum','Tonnes'])

# Set previous week's week number
df['PrevWeekNum']= df['WeekNum']-1
# roll back to week 52 if 0
df.loc[df['PrevWeekNum']==0,['PrevWeekNum']]=52

# Get the previous week's tonnage by doing a left outer merge to itself
df['PrevTonnes']=df.merge( df, left_on=['Category','PrevWeekNum'], right_on=['Category','WeekNum'], how='left' )['Tonnes_y']

# Calculate the difference
df['WeekDelta']= df['Tonnes']-df['PrevTonnes']
```

Results

```
   Category  WeekNum  Tonnes  PrevWeekNum  PrevTonnes  WeekDelta
0     Apple       51    20.0           50         NaN        NaN
1     Apple       52    19.0           51        20.0       -1.0
2     Apple        1    14.0           52        19.0       -5.0
3     Apple        2    15.2            1        14.0        1.2
4     Apple        3    17.0            2        15.2        1.8
5     Apple        4    17.0            3        17.0        0.0
6     Apple        5    18.0            4        17.0        1.0
7    Orange       51    10.5           50         NaN        NaN
8    Orange       52     9.0           51        10.5       -1.5
9    Orange        1     4.0           52         9.0       -5.0
10   Orange        2     7.0            1         4.0        3.0
11   Orange        3     8.0            2         7.0        1.0
```

Drop any columns you don't want using df.drop()

You should ideally also include a date or year in the data to avoid looking up the weekly tonnage from the wrong year.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add a couple of extra columns, and add them on the merge (left_on, right_on) but I seem to get wrong prevtonnes data, somehow.